# How to see $2^{{1}/{3}}$ is not included to $\mathbb Q(w)$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

put, $w=e^{i2\pi/9}$.
$\mathbb Q(w)$ is a splitting field of $x^9-1$ on $\mathbb Q$.
Then how to see $2^{1/3}$ is not included to $\mathbb Q(w)$?

Comment: How would you "start" this question? From the definition : so write down the definition of $2^{\frac 13} \in Q(\omega)$ and confirm it with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Galois closure of $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})/\Bbb Q$ is a non-Abelian group.
The extension $\Bbb Q(w)/\Bbb Q$ has an Abelian Galois group.
If $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})\subseteq\Bbb Q(w)/\Bbb Q$ then the Galois
closure of $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$ would be contained in $\Bbb Q(w)$.
But a subextension of an Abelian extension is Abelian.